# Navigation Controller in popover

Tags: ipad, uitableview, dynamic, uipopovercontroller

I am a total newbie in the ipad app development.

I am interested in creating an application where i have a popover showing a tableview with list of items. Then i select an item and the view drills to another tableview consisting of another list of items and a navigate back button as well.

the level to which i would be drilling down is dynamic.

Please guide me with appropriate resources to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it before and it works well!
Just assign this function to your button (perhaps an UIBarButtonItem):

```
UIPopoverController *popover;
bool isPopoverOpen = false;
-(void)openPopover{
    if(!isPopoverOpen){
        FirstViewController *firstViewCtrl = [[PartsViewCtrl alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navbar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewCtrl];
        [firstViewCtrl release];
        navbar.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT);
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navbar];
        [navbar release];
        popover.delegate = self;
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT);
        [popoverOnPartsView presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        isPopoverOpen = true;
    }else{
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [popover release];
        isPopoverOpen = false;
    }
}
```

And implement this function to FirstViewController which has an UITableView:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [secondViewController release];
}
```

Now you can add an UITableView to SecondViewController, Too. And use this scenario for other tables!

I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 4):

When you create the popover, you just need to allocate a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use this to manage the view hierarchy within the popover itself. A quick web search revealed [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development) which covers the things you need to know.

I also meant to add that you should get up to speed with Objective-C and iOS development in general. Don't try and blindly use things you've found on the net without understanding what you're actually doing :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks fr the early reply. I'll work on it and update if it works for me.

:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Do the following steps
```

1)In the action of button (by clicking on that button pop over should appear) write the code

*[here PopOverContentViewController is a viewController where i have table view and several list of items which should be displayed when the pop over arrives]*

```
 - (IBAction)callPopOver:(id)sender 
  {


    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    PopOverContentViewController1 *popOverContent = [[PopOverContentViewController1     alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopOverContentViewController1" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navbar = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:popOverContent];

    navbar.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(266, 200);
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navbar];
    popover.delegate = self;
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width / 2,   button.frame.size.height / 1, 1, 1) inView:button   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(266, 200) animated:YES]; 
    [popUpContent release];


    }
```

2)now to change the table view on clicking on any of the rows type this code in PopOverViewController.m

*[here PopOverViewController2 is the ViewController where we have the next table view to be displayed]*

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PopOverViewController2 *secondViewController = [[PopOverViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    [secondViewController release];
    }
```

3)to avoid the change in size of popover while navigation write the following code in viewDidLoad of both view controllers (ie PopOverContentViewController1 and PopOverContentViewController2)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(266, 200)];
 }
```