# Navigate between UITableview within a PopOver

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableview` within a PopOver, with a `UINavigationController`.

1) How to navigate to another `UITableview`, within the popover, when tapped on one of the cells of the first `UITableview` ?

2) Also, is it possible that the new `UITableview` that loads has a bigger size than the previous table within the popover? That is, the new bigger `UITableview` resizes the popover accordingly?

Comment: Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166291/navigation-controller-in-popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `UINavigationController method    pushViewController:animated:`
2. Use the `UIPopoverController method    setPopoverContentSize:animated:`